# ResponseStatusExceptionResolver custom logging

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, logging

Whenever I make some kind of requests to my API, then Spring Boot logs exceptions, if they were thrown. I'd like to tweak that a little bit.

For example, when I make a request `GET /api/entity/100` and there's no entity of id 100, then - in the service layer - I'll throw an exception `EntityNotFoundException` with some message and HTTP code.

The problem is that I do not want it logged in the console because it quickly makes it look like trash and spam. The log will look something like this: `WARN 15512 --- [nio-8433-exec-3] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolved [com.demo.mydomain.exceptions.classes.entity.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find entity of '100' id]`.

Obviously I can disable that by, for instance, adding this property `spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception=false`. However, this disables all the logs of `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver` and I'd like to maintain logging some other exceptions, like `AccessDeniedException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own resolver that extend `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver` and override its `logException()`. If the exception is the one that you do not want to log , return it. Something likes :

```java
public class MyResponseStatusExceptionResolver extends ResponseStatusExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    protected void logException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (ex instanceof EntityNotFoundException) {
            return;
        }
        super.logException(ex, request);
    }
}
```

Then configure to use it :

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void extendHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> resolvers) {
        var myResolver = new MyResponseStatusExceptionResolver();
        myResolver.setMessageSource(context);
        myResolver.setWarnLogCategory(myResolver.getClass().getName());
        resolvers.add(0, myResponseStatusExceptionResolver);
    }
}
```

The idea is the you put this customized exception resolver into the first position of the default exception resolver list such that it will always use it to resolve the exception before the default `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver`.

Please note that you must set the logging level of the customised exception resolver to WARN in order to have the exception logging behaviour that you want.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Your solution solves my problem. However, I'd like to note that I'm unsure why did you use `myResolver.setMessageSource(context)` as well as `myResolver.setWarnLogCategory(myResolver.getClass().getName());`. I removed both of these lines and it seems like it changed nothing. By default the logging level is `WARN`.